# Variables in Queries - Server-side Scripts

Tags: google-app-maker

I want to be able to build an SQL query using variables.

How can I create the equivalent of this PHP statement in a Google App Maker server-side script?

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE orderId = $orderNo";
```

-('$orderNo' as a variable)

This may be achieved through a calculated model, if so, I need to understand how to use variables within the calculated SQL query.

Like this: https://developers.google.com/appmaker/models/cloudsql#sql_calculated_model

The variable here ultimately needs to be an ID property on the page.

Entirely different approaches are welcome

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use datasource Query Builder (https://developers.google.com/appmaker/models/datasources#query_builder):
[image]

or hack into 'where' query property (server script):

```js
var newQuery = app.models.Company.newQuery();

newQuery.where = 'Name contains? :SearchText or Address contains? :SearchText or Website contains? :SearchText';
newQuery.parameters.SearchText = 'search term';
companies = newQuery.run()
```

You can find examples in templates (https://developers.google.com/appmaker/templates/). Q&A Forum (query builder), Partner Management (how to use 'where' query property).

Comment: Thank you sir! That led me to my solution!